# Syncfusion radialguage not working with maui intialize component failing

Tags: syncfusion, maui, .net-maui

I am trying to work with radialguages in maui using syncfusion library (syncfusion.maui.Gauges) but I was not able to work with it due Intialize component();.

Here is my mainpage.xaml.cs file where I'm getting the error.

namespace RadialGuagesMain;

public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

}

Comment: What is the verion of the Visual Studi? Could you use a new maui project without `InitializeComponent` error? Have you checked the prerequisites? https://www.nuget.org/packages/Syncfusion.Maui.Gauges/

Comment: Hi, Thanks for checking in. I am using Visual Studio 2022 Preview. It is a very simple default project I have just imported synsfusion gauges and when I try to add them it's not working.

Comment: Have you tried to update the Visual Studio and synsfusion package to the latest? Have you installed the .net 6.0 SDK? https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/6.0

Comment: Yes I have tried with the latest package of syncfusion also also tried with latest 5 versions. I am using the latest preview version of vs2022 with .net 6.

Comment: Have you followed the instructions that SyncFusion gives, for initializing their maui controls? Hint: its a line you must add to MauiApp.CreateMauiApp().